# How to generate descriptions on enums from XML documentation for Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a model with the following enum in my .NET Core web api project:

```
public enum Industries
{
    Undefined = 0,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting
    /// </summary>
    AgricultureForestryFishingAndHunting = 1,

    Mining = 2,

    Utilities = 3,

    Construction = 4,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Computer and Electronics Manufacturing
    /// </summary>
    ComputerAndElectronicsManufacturing = 5,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Other Manufacturing
    /// </summary>
    OtherManufacturing = 6,

    Wholesale = 7,

    Retail = 8,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Transportation and Warehousing
    /// </summary>
    TransportationAndWarehousing = 9,

    Publishing = 10,

    Software = 11,

    Telecommunications = 12,

    Broadcasting = 13,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Information Services and Data Processing
    /// </summary>
    InformationServicesAndDataProcessing = 14,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Other Information Industry
    /// </summary>
    OtherInformationIndustry = 15,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Finance and Insurance
    /// </summary>
    FinanceAndInsurance = 16,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Real Estate, Rental and Leasing
    /// </summary>
    RealEstateRentalAndLeasing = 17,

    /// <summary>
    ///    College, University, and Adult Education
    /// </summary>
    CollegeUniversityAndAdultEducation = 18,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Primary/Secondary (K-12) Education
    /// </summary>
    PrimarySecondaryK12Education = 19,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Other Education Industry
    /// </summary>
    OtherEducationIndustry = 20,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Health Care and Social Assistance
    /// </summary>
    HealthCareAndSocialAssistance = 21,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Arts, Entertainment, and Recreation
    /// </summary>
    ArtsEntertainmentAndRecreation = 22,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Hotel and Food Services
    /// </summary>
    HotelAndFoodServices = 23,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Government and Public Administration
    /// </summary>
    GovernmentAndPublicAdministration = 24,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Legal Services
    /// </summary>
    LegalServices = 25,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Scientific or Technical Services
    /// </summary>
    ScientificorTechnicalServices = 26,

    Homemaker = 27,

    Military = 28,

    Religious = 29,

    /// <summary>
    ///    Other Industry
    /// </summary>
    OtherIndustry = 30
}
```

I then wire up swashbuckle to include the XML documentation file:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "MySolution.xml"), true);

    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "MySolution.Client.xml"), true);

    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "MySolution.Common.xml"), true);

    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
        new Info {Title = "My Solution", Version = "v1"});

    c.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
    c.DescribeStringEnumsInCamelCase();
    c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();
    c.UseReferencedDefinitionsForEnums();
    c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
});
```

When running this and viewing the `swagger.json` document, I don't see my XML comments for the enum values at all, just the values:

```
"definitions": {
    ...
    "MySolution.Common.Models.Industries": {
        "enum": [
            "undefined",
            "agricultureForestryFishingAndHunting",
            "mining",
            "utilities",
            "construction",
            "computerAndElectronicsManufacturing",
            "otherManufacturing",
            "wholesale",
            "retail",
            "transportationAndWarehousing",
            "publishing",
            "software",
            "telecommunications",
            "broadcasting",
            "informationServicesAndDataProcessing",
            "otherInformationIndustry",
            "financeAndInsurance",
            "realEstateRentalAndLeasing",
            "collegeUniversityAndAdultEducation",
            "primarySecondaryK12Education",
            "otherEducationIndustry",
            "healthCareAndSocialAssistance",
            "artsEntertainmentAndRecreation",
            "hotelAndFoodServices",
            "governmentAndPublicAdministration",
            "legalServices",
            "scientificorTechnicalServices",
            "homemaker",
            "military",
            "religious",
            "otherIndustry"],
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

What am I missing to make this work?  I'm using v 2.5.0 of Swashbuckle, which looks like the latest and greatest.

Comment: The `IncludeXmlComments` was a pain on my rear for a while, the best solution I found was to recurse over all folders in the project loading all .xml files

Comment: Well, my xml files are loaded, it's just the enum information that's not coming through, as far as I can tell.

Comment: ... could it be a Bug or maybe not supported by OAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments for the enum values are not supported by the OAS (OpenAPI-Specification) :

> 5.5.1.1.  Valid values
>
> The value of this keyword MUST be an array.  This array MUST have at
> least one element.  Elements in the array MUST be unique.
>
> Elements in the array MAY be of any type, including null.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#items-object
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.1

Comment: Wow, that's... bizarre.  Seriously?!? Why would anyone think we wouldn't need to document the meaning and purpose of enum values?  That's insane.

Comment: There is a proposal to add it though: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Don't keep your hopes up on that proposal, it was created on Apr 29, 2015 and even if it gets approved today it will be a while before it gets implemented by the swagger-ui and included in swashbuckle